using winsock to connect over the internet (IPv6)
I am working on a video game and for it I am trying to add online multiplayer. I created my own winsock wrapper file to handle clients and servers, and it functions for LAN connections. However  when trying to connect clients over the internet the program fails to connect.
My code has 3 main functions for connecting clients, "createServer" which makes the server, "OpenClientConnection" which allows clients to connect, and "createClient" which connects a client to the open server. I have gotten a lot of this code from the Microsoft winsock help page and I wanted to see if anyone could help or provide useful resources on the matter. Thanks
bool Ipv6Server::createServer()
{
        //Result flag
    int _result;
    
    //Create the winsock data object
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    
    //Starts the WSA
    _result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    if (_result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed: " << _result << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    
    //Address information
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    hints;
                
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family   = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
    
    //Resolve the server address and port
    _result = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (_result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed: " << _result << "\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    //Creates the socket to listen to the connection
    mListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (mListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }


    //Binds the socket to an ip address and port
    _result = bind(mListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (_result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Bind failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(mListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    //Frees the address
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    
    return mListenSocket;
}


//Allows a new client to connect
bool Ipv6Server::openClientConnection()
{
    //Listens on a socket
    if (listen(mListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to listen: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        closesocket(mListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    //Accepts a connection
    
    mReceivers.push_back(Receiver{INVALID_SOCKET});
    std::cout << "Lisening for client\n";
    mReceivers[mClientCount].client = accept(mListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "Client found\n";
    if (mReceivers[mClientCount].client == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to accept connection: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        closesocket(mListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    
    mClientCount++;
    
    return true;
}


//Creates the client
bool Ipv6Client::createClient(const char* _server_ipv6)
{
    //Result flag
    int _result;
    
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    mReceiver.client = INVALID_SOCKET;
    
    //Starts the WSA
    _result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    if (_result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed: " << _result << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    
    //Address information
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr    = NULL,
                    hints;
                
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family   = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
    
    //Resolve server address and port
    _result = getaddrinfo(_server_ipv6, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (_result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed: " << _result << "\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    
    //Attempts to connect to server
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        //Creates a socket for connecting to
        mReceiver.client = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (mReceiver.client == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            std::cout << "Socket failed to connect to server: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }
        
        //Connects to server
        _result = connect(mReceiver.client, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (_result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(mReceiver.client);
            mReceiver.client = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    
    if (mReceiver.client == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect to server\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    
    //Creates the receiver
    createReceiver();
    
    return true;                
}

This application is meant to connect clients, and it does but only when they are on the same LAN. I am using IPv6 addresses because I know these address are globally route-able and it allowed me to avoid NAT for IPv4.

Well, hold on a minute.  Just because your machine has an IPv6 address does not mean you are reachable globally.  The connectivity issues are exactly the same -- you can't avoid NAT.  No one from outside your router can reach you unless you have a public IP address, and that probably belongs to your gateway/router.

Interesting, do you know if there is a way I could find the IP address and port of the server so I can connect from a different network?

@TimRoberts That is incorrect.  Every host on the internet can have a globally-routable ipv6 address (multiple, actually).  No NAT is needed for ipv6 (though ipv6 NAT does exist, so it's possible).  That doesn't necessarily mean OP's address is routable though.  For instance, fe80::/64 addresses are link-local.  Most home routers have firewalls that will default-deny inbound connections as well and will likely need to be configured to allow them.

Well, you have to KNOW the IP address of the server.  You can use https://whatismyip.com to find your external IP address.  That will tell you if your gateway even supports IPv6.

@Ian8tor You need to know the router's public WAN IP/port, this is what outside clients must connect to. And you need to configure the router to port-forward the WAN IP/port to the LAN IP/port that the server is bound to.

I cannot access the router since I live in an apartment, but is there a way I can find the specific IPv6 or IPv4 address and port that the server is bound to within the code. the whatismyip.com is helpful, but I would rather have the code print the IP addresses for ease of use (I know this isn't secure but it's currently just for testing)
